# How can you use multiple lines in a text area?

Tags: 6, entities

I'm probably missing something really simple here, but I can't seem to find it at all!

I want to have a text area for lyrics in my "Songs" content type.  Naturally, lyrics should be displayed one line per line, and with a space to distinguish verses, choruses etc... e.g.

> I got my head checked
>  By a jumbo jet
>  It wasn't easy
>  But
>   nothing is
>  No
>
> Woohoo!

When I put the above in a text area, I get:

I got my head checked By a jumbo jet It wasn't easy But nothing is No Woohoo!

How do I get this to display correctly?  I am using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the input format (just below the textarea) to Filtered HTML or Full HTML.

Comment: Aha!  That works!  I knew it'd be something simple I was overlooking - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) while viewing the field.

Comment: The code for viewing a field is hard-coded in a module, and it is not possible to opt for using `nl2br()` when viewing it.